# C sharp system IO saving text file problem

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Alright, I made a program which should work, but unfortunately doesn't. It loads a file saves the string and modifies it to display normal ASCII characters. The program doesn't bug, but the file doesn't change. Here is the part of the code :

```
string filePath = textBox1.Text;

if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath,Encoding.Unicode);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    sb.Replace('ą', 'a');
    ...
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, text , Encoding.Unicode);
}
```

Unfortunately even though i save the file as a Unicode one, it still doesn't change the file text. Where could my problem be? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, text, Encoding.Unicode);
```

should be:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString(), Encoding.Unicode);
```